# Assign a sound to each key / key combination

Tags: windows, gratis, audio

For a disabled person I'm looking for a program which allows assigning a sound to each key and key combination. For now, my intention is to speak the typed character out loud, so I have a key assignment like

- <kbd>A</kbd> = a.wav
- <kbd>B</kbd> = b.mp3
- ...
- <kbd>Z</kbd> = z.ogg
- <kbd>1</kbd> = one.wav
- ...
- <kbd>F1</kbd> = help.wav
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> = copy.wav

Note that I don't want to use TTS (text to speech) here, because it might not be flexible enough.

Such a program could potentially have other uses as well, e.g. it could be used in a workshop and pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> plays a bell sound to inform the participants that 50% of the time is over. Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> rings the final alarm bell.

The program should work on Windows (7 and 10 at least) and be gratis and hide in the tray. I imagine it would play WAV, MP3 and perhaps OGG files (optional).

So far I found [SoundPilot](http://www.colorpilot.com/soundpilot.html), but it's not free.

Comment: You might want to take a look at JAWS, a visually impaired friend of mine uses it...

Comment: Meanwhile I have implemented something similar myself as part of a trainee project: https://github.com/BorsMitutoyoCTL/Soundkey